# How to add StumbleUpon and Delicious Scripts to existing images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 images already, one for StumbleUpon and one for Delicious. Now I want to link it with the necessary script, I have spend a couple of hours now, and can't find the necessary good links.

I only find the ready made scripts, which include their own images etc. To give you an example of what I mean, the site I am working on is this one: http://www.icephoenix.co . I already have those images, I only want to call the script which bookmarks it etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Delicious code which was needed:

http://www.delicious.com/save" onclick="window.open('http://www.delicious.com/save?v=5&noui&jump=close&url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title), 'delicious','toolbar=no,width=550,height=550'); return false;

This is the Stumble Upon Code:

http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url={};title={}

PS. Replace the {} with the relevant url and title.

Answer (score 0):

The links as you've shown there shouldn't really use an `<img>` tag - you should be setting the icon image as a background to the `<a>` element with CSS. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/H5V3m/

It should be very simple to attach the ready-made scripts to the `<a>` element. Why don't you post a link to those scripts so we can take a look?

Comment: The answer below contains the code which I was looking for. Once found it was ok, but for a moment I was looking everywhere and didn't find what I need. Once I changed my search query a little bit, everything came into place.